# How to custom sort in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a set of values in Excel.

```
actionDetails_1_url
actionDetails_3_generationTime
actionDetails_2_url
actionDetails_10_url
```

When i sort them I get

```
actionDetails_1_url
actionDetails_10_url
actionDetails_2_url
actionDetails_3_generationTime
```

But i want it like this

```
actionDetails_1_url
actionDetails_2_url
actionDetails_3_generationTime
actionDetails_10_url
```

How to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a new column containing the number which occurs in between the underscores, and then to sort your data on that computed column.  Assuming the value `actionDetails_1_url` were in cell `A1`, here is a formula to extract the number:

```
= MID(A1,
      FIND("_", A1, FIND("_", A1) + 0) + 1,
      FIND("_", A1, FIND("_", A1) + 1) - FIND("_", A1, FIND("_", A1) + 0) - 1)
```

**Additional step:**

Copy this computed column into a third column, cast it to numeric, and then perform the sort.  If you just sort on the column coming from the formula above, then you still get the same behavior, because it will be a lexigraphic (string) sort.

A better design option going forward might be to maintain the state you need for sorting.

Comment: Did not change the output

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What does this formula give you?

Comment: Sorry, it gives me 1,3,2,10

Comment: Copy this new column to a new column and convert it to numeric, then sort.  I tested this and it works for me locally.

Comment: I have the base columns. I use the formula on a separate column and i get 1
3
2
10
Now i copy this and do paste special to a third colum. When i do a sort on it now it gives me : 1 10 2 3

Comment: No, you have to convert that third column to a _numeric_ type.  Highlight the column, press CTRL+1, and cast to numeric, then it will work.

Comment: I did that. I wish i could have shown you the snapshot. Even if the 3rd column gets sorted, how will it effect the first column

Comment: Highlight all three columns, press ALT + D + S, then choose the third column for sorting, in ascending order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115470/discussion-between-diganta-bharali-and-tim-biegeleisen).